# A simple math in Python that's hard for me

Tags: function, math

Please help me. I'm trying to learn Python and I'm very beginner. I tried reading and watching videos but I don't understand this logic:

```
def myFunction(y):
    x = y + y #Local
    print(x)
    return x
x = 5 #Global
myFunction(x)
print(x)
```

I get the values 10 and 5.

Really, I can't understand why 10. This is breaking my mind. If x equals 5, than the result of the line 2 shouldn't be 2.5? I have 5 = y + y.

My mind is on a loop. Please help, you're my only hope.

Comment: As commented, the `x` inside `myFunction` is a local variable to that function's scope, and different to the `x` marked as global. When calling `myFunction(x)` you are passing the value of the global `x` to the function. Inside the function, the passed value is given to a local variable `y`, summed twice with local `x` and it's this `x` that gets printed and whose value is returned. Meanwhile, the global `x` was not changed and is printed in the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing **x as the argument of your function** `myFunction()`.
Thus if `x=5` you get:

```
myFunction(5):
   x = 5 + 5 
   return(x) #10
```

this is why you are getting 10. If you change `x=5` to `x=10` you will see that the result of the function will be 20 and so on...

You are not replacing the `x` in the function itself. However, the `x` you stated will indeed remain a global variable and thus will be printed on the second line.

Comment: Thank you. Now I see. Dumb me. So easy.